# Concatenate DataFrames in vertical and horizontal at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I would like to concatenate two df in both directions at the same time.
It means, if the index does not exist, it is created.
And if the column does not exist, it is created also.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A4'],
                    'D': ['D4']},
                    index=[4])

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['E4'],
                    'F': ['F4']},
                    index=[4])


result = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

It gives :

```
    A    B    C    D    F
0  A0   B0   C0   D0  NaN
1  A1   B1   C1   D1  NaN
2  A2   B2   C2   D2  NaN
3  A3   B3   C3   D3  NaN
4  A4  NaN  NaN   D4  NaN
4  E4  NaN  NaN  NaN   F4
```

Instead of :

```
    A    B    C    D    F
0  A0   B0   C0   D0  NaN
1  A1   B1   C1   D1  NaN
2  A2   B2   C2   D2  NaN
3  A3   B3   C3   D3  NaN
4  E4  NaN  NaN   D4   F4
```

Comment: Is that really the expected result? What happened to the `'A': ['A4']` from df2? Should df3 have `'A': ['E4']` or `'E': ['E4']`?

Comment: Yes the problem is to have df3 with 'A': ['E4']. Because when concatenating, you fill an existing cell & a new one. Even doing this does not help: 
`result = pd.concat([df1, df2])` `result = pd.concat([result, df3], axis=1)`

Comment: The question title is misleading. Your issue inst that you need to concat on two axes, the issue is that you are trying to assign two different values to [4, 0] in your final frame and you want Python/Pandas to retain one of them and discard the other. You need to provide criteria for how that decision should be made